# Getting "blocked by CORS policy" error after `npm run build`

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-build

I am a newbie to React. I created a React app which is working fine on `npm start`. But after `npm run build`, I am not getting full page info. i.e. I am getting the nav bar but the main content is not available. On the console, the following error is present:

> 'file:///C:/Users/pkv97/OneDrive/Desktop/ReactJs/CodeWithHarry/TextUtilsHarry/text_utils/build/%E2%80%9Dmanifest.json%E2%80%9D' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

I tried running `npm build` on D drive as it is searching files on OneDrive but still facing the same issue. On `npm build`, it should work the same as it is working on `npm start`.

Can someone guide how to fix it?

Comment: You are opening a local file in the browser that tries to execute an ajax request to some backend. And as the errors says [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is not supported for `file://...`   `npm start` most probably create a local http server and you are accessing this file via `http://localhost/....` And that's why it works ...

Comment: how can i fix it?? any solution

Comment: Serve it via a http server ...

Comment: I wonder why you want to do `npm run build`?

Comment: For deploy my react app i do not want to use npm start every time to load my react app

Answer (score -4):

Re install NPM and Start then it'll work properly.

```
npm install --save && npm run build
```

Comment: No, most certainly reinstalling npm won't resolve a CORS issue ...

Comment: correct, its not working still facing same issue